# Merging from another clone with my own clone before pushing to main clone?

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a project being version controlled by mercurial.

I have a clone. My friend has a clone.

My friend made some changes to his clone, and then pushed them to the main clone. I have made some changes to my clone, and am ready to push to the main clone. However, I want to incorporate his changes into my own clone, before I push to the main clone (I think that's the right way to go?)

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Don't fear the merge.  Many of us who cut our teeth on cvs get a sinking feeling when we have to merge branches.  Branching and merging is natural and easy with Mercurial.

1. Commit all your changes to your local hg

   `hg pull` to grab all the new nodes from the main repo, in your case these will make a new head

   `hg merge` to create your current working file state as a merge of two parent nodes

   use `hg resolve -l` to list any conflicted files, then edit them until you are happy

   use `hg resolve -m`  to mark the fixed files as resolved

   use `hg commit` to actually commit the merge of the two parent nodes

   use `hg push` to let your friend get a copy of them

Remember mercurial deals in changesets.  A changeset is just another name for a snapshot state of the project at some instant in time.
Generally every changeset has one parent changeset, the previously committed state on which the state is based. The exception is the merge operation, which is special because it has two parent changesets.

Every changeset has zero or more children changesets.
If it has zero children, a changeset is a "head".
If it has more than 1 child, then it represents a divergent branch of development.

Answer (score 0):

`hg pull -u` from the main clone. This will get all new changes from the main clone (including your friend's) and update your working copy.